# How to upload multiple files in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get a problem to upload multiple file in React Native, today I try to look for many examples, but fail all, just title and content send to database, but files are fail, this is my script :

This is data in 'this.state.files', I get this data from file picker, you can find here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-picker

[image]

This is my post function :
[image]

This is my Service :
[image]

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Setup A Form:

```
let data = new FormData();
```

Fill Form Out:

```
this.state.selectedImages.forEach((item, i) => {
  data.append("doc[]", {
    uri: item.uri,
    type: "image/jpeg",
    name: item.filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
  });
});
```

Submit Data:

```
fetch(`${config.apiBase}/load/${this.props.id}/uploadconfirmation`, {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.user.token}`,
  },
  body: data,
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Success",
      "Bill of Loading Uploaded Successfully!",
      [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => that.props.close() }],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("error uploading images: ", err);
  });
```

This tutorial is from Ariel Salem :

[Blockquote](https://medium.com/@ariel.salem1989/how-to-upload-multiple-files-react-native-e9577a5de106)

Comment: not working. I have tested my backend code with the postman.it was working fine. but in-app this code is not working.